# floating pins in arduino

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microprocessor, arduino-uno

i have an arduino board when i use analogeread to read the value of A0 without connecting any wire to it ,gives me a value not zero in serial monitor. is my arduino dead or what is the problem? i would to know what happend to my arduino and how to fix

Comment: Explain what you expect. Your question is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: why would you expect a zero reading when you did not connect zero volts to the pin?

Comment: Ironically enough, this is how the [Arduino Random seed is recommended to work](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/), so this is a known, and exploited for a useful purpose, issue.

Comment: @RonBeyer: that's a terrible random seed, yielding only 256 sequences, making it trivial. don't link to that, for the sake of all of us...

Comment: @dandavis 1024 sequences, theoretically. Probably far far fewer in practice, though...

Answer (score 2):

It's a normal behaviour. When you don't have anything connected to the pin impedance of it is really high. It basically starts to behave like an antenna an picks up everything from the surroundings. To make it stop floating you should connect something you want to measure, or a really high value resistor to ground (hundreds of kOhms even) to increase the impedance. Keep in mind however that it will behave like a divider when you connect something.